# What does ctrl+shift+B do?

Tags: delphi, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, delphi-xe7

When I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. 
In Delphi XE7 (with CN_Pack installed) I see the following:

[image]

When I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> again the `>^` disappears. 
What does this mean?

According to the Delphi documentation:

> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>  Displays the buffer list.

This is something else though, what is it?

Comment: FWIW, I have Delphi XE8.1 installed, and for me Ctrl+Shift+B appears to do nothing at all, so this must be a CN_Pack thing.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError In Delphi XE8 all kinds of keyboard shortcuts are broken, even CTRL + F to find.

Comment: What does the CN-Pack documentation say?

Comment: @Jerry: `Ctrl+Q,F` works fine for me (in XE8.1 - Wordstar settings), and I am used to things being "broken", because I use a German keyboard and many of these shortcuts only seem to work for ASCII keyboards.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, it says nothing on this subject.

Comment: It would be really cool to have a plugin that would list all the key mappings, which plugin has used them and the purpose they serve.

Comment: https://github.com/NickRing/Delphi-Shortcut-Finder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your screenshot i see that you have installed the "Bookmarks" plugin also. This plugin registeres this shortcut to set a temporary "caret marker"

From their website:

> Sometimes you don’t want a permanent marker; you just want a way to quickly navigate back to where you were. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to drop a temporary caret bookmark, and press Escape to jump back to it.

See: https://parnassus.co/delphi-tools/bookmarks/

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> is to show the list of edit buffers being maintained by the IDE.  Roughly speaking, this corresponds to files open in the editor, but also may refer to files opened by the IDE but not currently open in a visual editor.

For example, after opening one of my scratch test projects, the IDE opens the main form file but also the project DPR.  Only the main form source is initially loaded into an editor window, but the IDE is maintaining an edit buffer for the DPR 'behind the scenes'.

So my editor has a tab for **fMain**, but <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> presents a dialog listing both this file and the DPR:

[image]

If  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> is doing anything else in your IDE then either you or some package installed in your IDE have re-assigned the shortcut, in which case the Delphi documentation and standard behaviour obviously does not apply (or there is a bug in your particular Delphi IDE).

Comment: Actually Ctrl+B, in older versions at least (up to XE2) The buffer list is (was) sample code for the ToolsAPI, usually located in C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Samples\Delphi\VCL\ToolsAPI\Editor KeyBinding . The relevant binding is `BindingServices.AddKeyBinding([ShortCut(Ord('B'), [ssCtrl])], BufferListProc, nil);`